# html: Align a sentence with image

Tags: html, css

I am working on a very simple html with some css style. I have a difficulties to algin an image with a paragraph. Suppose my div section has an image and a paragraph like this:

```
<div>
<img border="1" src="cake.jpg" width="100" height="70">
Tom's review: This is the best cake that I have ever had...
</div>
```

The paragraph appears on the "bottom right" of the image but I want it to be appeared on "top right" of the the image.

I know this question is simple but I am very new to html. Can anyone here help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to float the image left.

```
<div>
<img border="1" src="cake.jpg" width="100" height="70" style="float: left;">
Tom's review: This is the best cake that I have ever had...
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;"><img border="1" src="gtld-lifecycle.jpg" width="100" height="70"></div>
<div style="float: left;">Tom's review: This is the best cake that I have ever had...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want you paragraph to appear at the top - right put your image after the paragraph.

```
<div>
   <p>Tom's review: This is the best cake that I have ever had...</p>
   <img border="1" src="cake.jpg" width="100" height="70"/><br/>
</div>
```